# MySQL getting column using DATEDIFF inside IF

Tags: mysql, datediff

I'm trying to get column 'Returned On Time' using DATEDIFF and IF functions

```
SELECT
IF(DATEDIFF(day, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date) <= film.rental_duration, 
   (COUNT(rental.rental_id) AS 'Returned On Time'))
FROM rental, film
```

But all I get is error, and I don't really understand how exactly DATEDIFF works and I don't even know if I can use COUNT inside the IF function

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: There is a lot wrong in that query. Please explain what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an aggregate function in the consequence of an `IF`. The `IF` expression is being applied to a single row, it doesn't make sense to aggregate the result.

You're also missing the joining condition between the two tables.

And the arguments you're using for `DATEDIFF()` are incorrect, they're more appropriate for TIMESTAMPDIFF. `DATEDIFF()` only takes two arguments, and the later one should be first.

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date) <= film.rental_duration) AS returned_on_time
FROM rental 
JOIN film ON rental.film_id = film.id
```